# How to add class if used started scroll inside div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have atleast 4 div boxes which needs add new class after started to scroll to bottom. The same class need to be removed if the user scrolled to top.

Refer this link for beter understanding. http://jsfiddle.net/xj4wbv5c/5/

Here we need to add class `scrolled` if user started scroll and remove class `scrolled` once the scroll bar touch the top after scrolling.

I already tried something but it doesn't help. Please suggest.

Comment: You are reading $(window).scrollTop - what you want to read is the current divs scrollTop which can be read using $(this).scrollTop in the scroll handler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close: http://jsfiddle.net/xj4wbv5c/6/

```
var header = $(".makescroll");
 $(".makescroll").scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        if (scroll >= 10) {
            $(this).addClass("scrolled");
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("scrolled");
        }
 });
```

You need to check when the element is scrolled, not the window, so I swapped $(window) with $(this). and also in the add and remove class I swapped with $(this). $(this) in this context means "the element that has fired the event (the div itself)".

Comment: Damn. I was seconds away!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/xj4wbv5c/7/

I used $(this) instead of the var header to only apply the class to each instance of the scroll container.

```
 var header = $(".makescroll");
 $(".makescroll").scroll(function() {
    var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
    if (scroll > 10) {
        $(this).addClass("scrolled");
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass("scrolled");
    }
});
```